# Internal error while returning Python data

Tags: python, flask

when opening `http://127.0.0.1:5000` on in my browser, i got following error. I tried to find the error online but nothing helped. i have following server error:

`Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from flask import jsonify
import random

@app.route('/')
def Calutlate():
    arr = []

    for i in range(10):
        n = random.randint(-10,35)
        arr.append(n)

    som = 0

    for item in arr:
        som += item

    avg = som / 10

    return jsonify(avg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Comment: The logs of the server should have the exception trace.

Comment: @rdas where and how can i change them?

Comment: Whereever you're runnig the flask server.

Comment: @rdas And what is the exception?

Comment: ... there is no way to know withou you adding the logs from the server in the question. Please go to your setup. Find where your flask server is running. Get the logs from it. Add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is around your return function jsonify.

jsonify serializes data to JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format, wraps it in a Response object with the application/json mimetype.

You actually don't give it a json format string which may create a potential problem.
I recommend you just to make a simple return statement like:
`return avg`

Comment: Yes thanks! i returned it like this: `return str(avg)`, because it need to return a string